# Implementation Question about Thin Wire Method of Moments

Tags: electromagnetism, computational-physics, antennas, radio-frequency

I am currently trying to implement a simple $1 \textrm{D}$ thin-wire method of moments code in Python to practice E&M and numerical methods. I am following Gibson's "The Method of Moments in Electromagnetics" and I am using piecewise linear basis and testing functions (triangle functions). However, I am a bit unclear about how to implement the "self terms" in the impedance matrix.

The triangle functions are defined as follows:

[image: Triangle Functions (source: Gibson)]

The impedance matrix elements (for the $m^{\textrm{th}}$ and $n^{\textrm{th}}$ basis and testing functions) are defined as follows

$$ \begin{split}
Z_{mn}^{E J} & = j \omega \mu \int_{\mathbf{f}_{m}} \mathbf{f}_{m} \!\left( \mathbf{r} \right) \cdot \int_{\mathbf{f}_{n}} \mathbf{f}_{n} \!\left( \mathbf{r}^{\prime} \right) G \!\left( \mathbf{r}, \mathbf{r}^{\prime} \right) d \mathbf{r}^{\prime} d \mathbf{r} \\
& - \frac{j}{\omega \epsilon} \int_{\mathbf{f}_{m}} \nabla \cdot \mathbf{f}_{m} \!\left( \mathbf{r} \right) \int_{\mathbf{f}_{n}} \nabla^{\prime} \cdot \mathbf{f}_{n} \!\left( \mathbf{r}^{\prime} \right)  G \!\left( \mathbf{r}, \mathbf{r}^{\prime} \right) d \mathbf{r}^{\prime} d \mathbf{r}
\end{split} \tag{1} \label{1} $$

If the triangles have overlapping segments (for instance, if $m = n$, $m = n + 1$ or $m = n - 1$) then special care needs to be taken to avoid the divergence in the Green's function. In the book, this is done analytically and they derive the following result for the "self-term contributions" to the above expression:

$$\frac{1}{4 \pi} \sum_{p = 1}{M} w_{p} \!\left( x_{p} \right) \left[ j \omega \mu f_{m} \!\left( x_{p} \right) S_{1} \!\left( x_{p} \right) - \frac{j}{\omega \epsilon} S_{2} \!\left( x_{p} \right) \right] \tag{2} \label{2} $$

where the $w_{p}$ are weights for the Gaussian quadrature points $x_{p}$, $f_{m}$ is the $m^{\textrm{th}}$ testing function and $S_{1,2}$ are the analytical solution that gets rid of the divergence problem. My question regards where and how to apply this "self-term" equation. As I understand it, there are $3$ cases when I compute the matrix elements:

1. There is no overlap at all; the matrix element can be found through simple numerical quadrature.
2. There is a total overlap of the basis and testing function; the matrix element needs to be split up into $4$ sub integrals - two relating to the two overlapping segments (say, $x_{1} - x_{2}$ in the above figure if $m = n = 1$) and two relating to the non-overlapping segments (say, $x_{1} - x_{2}$ and $x_{2} - x_{3}$ in the above figure if $m = n = 1$). The non-overlapping segments can be integrated normally and the overlapping ones must be integrated using the self-term correction.
3. Only a single segment overlaps (e.g. $m = 1$ and $n = 2$). There are two sub-cases depending on whether $m > n$. Here (for the case $m = 1$ and $n = 2$), you integrate over the segment pairs $x_{1} -x_{2}/x_{2} - x_{3}$, $x_{1} - x_{2}/x_{3} - x_{4}$ and $x_{2} - x_{3}/x_{3} - x_{4}$ normally and use the self term correction for the overlapping segment $x_{2} - x_{3}$.

Also, it seems to me that, even though the singularity only happens EXACTLY when the quadrature points overlap, you apply the "self-term correction" to the entire segment where the overlap is happening.

Is my understanding of the algorithm correct?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Author here.

Throughout the book I generally try to separate contributions to the MoM matrix into three groups:

1. Self Terms: These are due to integrations on overlapping elements where the singularity occurs. These will occur when a basis function is tested with itself on an element, or by neighboring basis functions also having support on that element. On these, special attention must be applied to the integrations as the kernel has a strong variation directly around the singularity. Often you will see closed-form solutions for the double integrals over these elements.
2. Near Terms: These are due to integrations on elements which do not overlap but are very close together. These can also occur when a basis function is tested with itself on those elements, or by neighboring basis functions also having support on those elements. Again, these integrals should be treated carefully as the kernel will still have significant variation being close to the singularity. With these, you will often see a combination of numerical and analytical integrations for the outer and innermost integrals. Note that neighboring basis functions will often have a combination of near and self terms that add together to yield their total MoM matrix element.
3. Far Terms: These are due to integrations on elements which do not overlap and are not very close together. As far as what comprises when two elements are "not very close", there is no set definition, in practice you will use some sort of heuristic to determine it. For example, you might consider elements separated by more than some number of wavelengths to be "far" elements. With far terms, you will typically use simple numerical integrations for the outer and innermost integrals, having lower numbers of quadrature points, which will be faster to calculate. This is an important consideration when dealing with three-dimensional problems having many unknowns, as you will want to minimize the run time as much as possible.

You will see this pattern also applied in later chapters of the book when discussing two and three-dimensional problems.